# Converting numpy array of str to byte string

Tags: python

I'm really new in python. I have a numpy array of str that I woud like to convert, as it is, to a bytes string.

```
v = np.array([['2B', '0E', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']])
```

Result should be:

```
b'\x2b\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I tried bytes, encode, and many other exotic solutions but without success.
Could anyone help me with that, please ?

Comment: Did you try [tobytes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html)?

Comment: Running [v = np.array([['2B', '0E', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']])
v.tobytes()] returns [b'2\x00\x00\x00B\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00E\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects)

```py
bytes([int(x, 16) for x in v[0]])
```

**Output**

```
b'+\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Me looking at your array and the desired result suggests

that the result simply added a `\x` to and lower-cased each string.

Like so:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([['2B', '0E', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']])
v = '\\'+'\\x'.join([b.lower() for i in v for b in i])
print(v.encode('utf8'))
```

Output:

```
b'\\2b\\x0e\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'
```

Comment: Wenn I run your code, it returns [b'\\2b\\x0e\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'] ?

Comment: The extra backslashes are only there to escape backslashes. It is actually still equivalent to it without extra backslashes. Just try `print(v.encode('utf8').decode('asciil'))`.

Comment: But wenn I run [v = np.array([['2B', '0E', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']])
v = '\\'+'\\x'.join([b.lower() for i in v for b in i])
vb=v.encode('utf8')
vb==b'\x2b\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'] it returns [false] ?